# What is the diffrence between these three regular expressions

Tags: regex, perl

What is the main difference between the following 3 regular expressions.

1) `/^[^0-9]+$/`

2)`/[^0-9]+/`

3) `m/[^0-9]+/`

I am really trying to understand this, since researching online has not helped me much I was hoping I could find some help here.

Answer (score 3):

All of them have [^0-9]+, which is one or more characters that are **not** the numbers `0`, `1`, ... to `9`.

- The first one `/^[^0-9]+$/` is anchored at the start and end of the string, so it will match any string that only contains non-digits.
- The second one `/[^0-9]+/` is not anchored, so it matches any string that contains at least one (or more) non-digits.
- The third one `m/[^0-9]+/` is the same as the second, but uses the [`m//` match operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/m.html) explicitly.

For a good explanation, check out [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) for the [first](https://regex101.com/r/eS7nO8/1) and [second](https://regex101.com/r/eS7nO8/2) regex.

Comment: Does it take into account the newline character? Because in one of the example I have seen, when `/[^0-9]+/` is used, a line with just the number 4 on it is a match. But when `m/[^0-9]+/` is used  and a chop() function is used on that same line, the line with just 4 on it is no longer a match .

Comment: I don't understand completely what you mean. Why don't you try yourself? You can also do `use re 'debug' ;` to get additional explanations of what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between a regular expression and the match operator which takes a regular expression as its operand.

You only have two regular expressions there - `^[^0-9]+$` and `[^0-9]+`. Option 3 uses the same regex as option 2, but it uses a different version of the match operator.

The difference between 1 and 2 is that 1 is anchored at the start and the end of the string, whereas 2 isn't anchored at all.

So 1 says "match the start of the string, followed by one or more non-digits, followed by the end of the string". 2 says "match one or more non-digits anywhere in the string".

Does that help at all?

Comment: Does 2 / 3 consider a newline character to be a match? Because in a example I have seen , the number "4" is on its own line and when /[^0-9]+/ is used it matches with that line. But when a chop() function is used and the newline character is removed, the line is no longer matched.

Comment: Is your question "does a newline match `[^0-9]`, then I would have thought that was pretty simple to test - `perl -E'say "\n" =~ /[^0-9]/ ? "Yes" : "No"'` (that prints "Yes")

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `[^0-9]` is common to these three regexes, and will match any single character that is *not* a decimal digit

1. `/^[^0-9]+$/`

   This *anchors* the pattern to the beginning and end of the string, and insists that it contains one or more non-digit characters

   The circumflex `^` is a zero-width anchor that matches the beginning of the string

   The dollar sign `$` is also a zero-width anchor that will match either at the end of the string, or before a newline character if that newline is the last in the string. So this will match `"aaa"` and `"aaa\n"` but not `"aa7bb\n"`
2. `/[^0-9]+/`

   This has no anchors, and so will return *true* if the string contains at least one non-digit character anywhere

   It will match `"12x345"` and *fail* to match `"12345"`. Note that a trailing newline counts as a non-digit character, so this pattern will match `"123\n"`
3. `m/[^0-9]+/`

   This is identical to #2, but with the `m` placed explicitly. This is unnecessary if you are using the default slashes for delimiters, but it can be convenient to use something different if you are matching a pattern for, say, a file path, which itself contains slashes

   Using `m` lets you choose your own delimiter, for example `m{/my/path}` instead of `/\/my\/path/`

In essence, #1 is asking whether the string is *wholly composed of* non-digit characters, while #2 and #3 are identical, and test whether the string *contains at least one* non-digit character

Comment: Does 2 / 3 consider a newline character to be a match? Because in a example I have seen , the number "4" is on its own line and when /[^0-9]+/ is used it matches with that line. But when  a chop() function is used and the newline character is removed, the line is no longer matched.

Comment: @J.Doe: Yes. A newline is just like any other character for every regex construct apart from `$`. As I said, `[^0-9]+` will match anything that contains at least one character as long as there is a non-digit in there. So it will match `"\n"` just fine. When you are reading lines of text from a file or from the terminal you *must* `chomp` the result as the newline will confuse any checking that you do. Checking for an all-numeric input should be `next unless /\S/ and not /\D/` i.e. skip this line unless has non-whitespace and no non-digits